# Bound on the number of maximum matchings in a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

It is [known](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2578.pdf) that the number of perfect matchings in a graph is bounded above by the integer part of the square root of the permanent of its adjacency matrix. But, suppose I take the square root of the permanent of the adjacency matrix of an odd order graph, then what does its integer part bound? Does it bound the number of distinct maximum matchings?

In the paper referred above, it is proved that the permanent of the adjacency matrix measures the number of $2$-spanning subgraphs that consist of even cycles. Suppose, even for an even order graph, if it does not have a perfect matching, then does the square root of the number of spanning $2$-regular subgrpahs bound the number of maximum matchings? Any lights on these matters? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: For number of perfect matchings look up [hafnian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafnian)

Comment: @RobertIsrael great! Does hafnian of odd order graph similarly give number of maximum matchings?

Comment: This permanent may well be zero while maximal matchings always exist